# ftp_connect in php fails

Tags: php, ftp

I want to connect to a remote server whose ip adress is xx.xxx.xxx.xx to later write on a file on it. Here my php code:

```
<?php
$remote_file = 'test_remote.txt';
$file = 'test.txt';

$conn_id = ftp_connect('xx.xxx.xxx.xx') or die("Could not connect")
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'name', 'passwd');

if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

I get the error "Could not connect"....

If I do

ssh name@xx.xxx.xxx.xx and entered the password it works fine. What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `ssh` and `ftp` are two completely different things. Can you do `ftp xx.xxx.xxx.xx` and login with the user and password?

Comment: no I can't If I do ftp xx.xxx.xxx.xx I get ftp: connect: Connection timed out....

Comment: Is there an ftp server up and running? It could also be a firewall problem.

Comment: sftp xx.xxx.xxx.xx on the other hand work

Comment: Is the port the standard 21 one or anything else?!

Comment: `sftp` simulates ftp over an ssh connection. `ftp_connect` uses real ftp.

Comment: ok. Could it been a problem of settings on the remote server?

Comment: I opened the 21 port and changed the rules in ip tables but it is still not connecting and vsftpd is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install ssh ftp extension, you can view the download documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php)

When you have installed it and its working properly(remember to restart your webserver after installation), you can do the following:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('ip/address', 'port');
if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password') {
        $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
        $fileStream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://" . $sftp . "pathToFile", 'w');
        //Write your data with fwrite($fileStream, $data)
}
```